# Overlay of image on image

Tags: html

Im new to css and trying to get an image to overlay another image multiple times. So the orange dots overlay the images. In the same spot for multiple images.

[image: Overlay]

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drd2k.png)

Comment: Can you show us your current code structure?

Comment: Please update your question with how far you have got. Add your html and CSS Code and mention clearly what you want to do and then probably someone can  help.

Comment: @MihailMinkov Added the current code

Comment: @Fergguy please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is to play with css `position` property.

give to parent element `position: relative` and to the overlaying child `position: absolute`, then play with the exact position using `left` and `top` properties.

should be something like this:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.badge {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img width="170" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1097456/pexels-photo-1097456.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"/>
  <img width="40" class="badge" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1977/1977845.png"/>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <img width="170" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1097456/pexels-photo-1097456.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"/>
  <img width="40" class="badge" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1977/1977845.png"/>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <img width="170" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1097456/pexels-photo-1097456.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"/>
  <img width="40" class="badge" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1977/1977845.png"/>
</div>
```